# Mixing MVC Razor and Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Throughout my app, I'd like to use Razor for all functionality related to Reading, and leverage knockoutJS and AJAX for CUD operations.

In my profile view, I've done the following:

```
<div>
    <h4>About Me</h4>
    <!-- ko if: !isEditingAboutMe() -->
    <p>@Model.User.AboutMe</p>
    @if (Model.CurrentUserCanEdit)
    {
        <a data-bind="click: editAboutMe">edit</a>
    }
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: isEditingAboutMe() -->
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.AboutMe, new { data_bind = "value: aboutMe" })
    <a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe">save</a>
    <a data-bind="click: cancelAboutMe">cancel</a>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

This way search engines can at least crawl the content, and users with javascript enabled can perform CUD operations.

My problem above is that - using AJAX, if I click "save", how to I bind the new value to the Razor model (fourth line down)?

Corresponding JS:

```
function ProfileVm() {
    var self = this;

    self.aboutMe = ko.observable();

    self.saveAboutMe = function() {
        // AJAX call, after success close the field
        self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
    };

    self.cancelAboutMe = function() {
        // just for testing, would revert the value in practice
        self.isEditingAboutMe(false);
    };

    self.isEditingAboutMe = ko.observable(false);
    self.editAboutMe = function() {
        self.isEditingAboutMe(true);
    };

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ProfileVm());
})
```

Also - feedback regarding the "properness" of this approach is welcome.

Comment: What does your `saveAboutMe` function do?

Comment: it calls an AJAX endpoint and returns either success or fail.  If success, it makes isEditing(false), but the value doesn't get reflected in the view.

Comment: Then make that `Action` return the newly updated model (as JSON), and re-apply it to Knockout.

Comment: @haim770 - MVC Action?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I guess i misunderstood your question, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear why you're using Knockout only for write operations (CUD) and not also for read. doing so can solve your problem automatically:

Instead of:

```
<p>@Model.User.AboutMe</p>
```

You should follow the Knockout way, so you'll have a two-way model binding:

```
<p data-bind="text: aboutMe()"></p>
```

Now, once the `aboutMe` field is updated, Knockout will make sure the data within the `<p>` element will be updated as well.

**Edit:**

Since you want search engines visibility of the user details, you can try this:

```
<p data-bind="text: aboutMe()">@Model.User.AboutMe</p>
```

This way, simple retrieval of the server response (without Script invocation) would indeed include the desired text, but once Knockout will kick-in (almost immediately) you'll still have full Model Binding with fresh data.

Comment: Because then Google won't see the value, nor will users with JS disabled.  Right?

Comment: Very cool, I like this approach.  Now I just have to push the model data into the knockout observables within the view, right?  Would you consider that messy (having script tags in the view, yuck)?

Comment: The 'regular' way of doing it is something like `ko.applyBindings(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));`, then bind your model as a whole. but if you're only going to update the `aboutMe` string and already have the Ajax that sends it back to server, you can stay with your current code and change (line 4): `self.aboutMe = ko.observable('@Model.User.AboutMe');`

Comment: I can do this in the javascript, and not the view?  That would be magical. Trying now..

Comment: If your `ProfileVm` code is in a separate `.js` file, the line `@Model.User.AboutMe` would not be interpreted by Razor.